# Knockout JS and simple functions

Tags: javascript, function, object, knockout.js

I hope this question was not already asked :p

Cutting straight to the point, i'm learning knockout and would like to do something extra in their tutorial. This picture link should be very useful:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHL7M.png ...
On an airplane, there are meals which cost money and a selection box updates the cost automatically. I want to add an input box which multiplies the meal cost by the quantity, but I don't know how to do this with knockout.

```js
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[2]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[1])
    ]);
    //Something extra I want to know how to do with knockout, i just want the "total" to be the "quantity" times the price of the "meal"
    var mealPrice = //what should go here?!?!?!
    this.quantity = ko.observable(1) //is this correct?
    var quantity = this.quantity
    var finalPrice = function() {
        quantity * mealPrice;
    }
    self.addSeat = function() {
        self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
//end
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Total</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: quantity" /></td>
            <td data-bind="text: finalPrice"></td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>
```

The 5th comment in the view model is the part where I want to put the new function.

Sorry about the easy question, i'm very new to all of this in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a computed property. This is a property that has a dependency on other observables and will be automatically updated whenever any of the dependencies change. You would add this computed property to the `SeatReservation` to get the total price for each seat's meal.

```
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
    self.quantity = ko.observable(1);
    this.finalPrice = ko.computed(function() {
        var quantity = self.quantity(),
               meal = self.meal() || {},
               price = meal.price || 0;
        return price * quantity;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Although I noticed that ko.pureComputed doesn't work, but ko.computed does... :d